# Are users only allowed to own 16 assets with pallet-assets?

Tags: pallet, assets, statemint, frame-system

Every new token a user holds in `pallet_assets` increases the consumer count for that user +1. And most chains set the `MaxConsumers` of `frame_system` to 16.

Both `mint_into` and `transfer` call at some point on `can_increase`, which calls `can_accrue_consumers`. And if the asset is not set as sufficient, then it expects to be able to increase the consumers

> substrate > frame > assets > src > functions.rs > impl Pallet > can_increase()

```rust
pub(super) fn can_increase(
    id: T::AssetId,
    who: &T::AccountId,
    amount: T::Balance,
    increase_supply: bool,
) -> DepositConsequence {
    let details = match Asset::<T, I>::get(&id) {
        Some(details) => details,
        None => return DepositConsequence::UnknownAsset,
    };
    if increase_supply && details.supply.checked_add(&amount).is_none() {
        return DepositConsequence::Overflow
    }
    if let Some(account) = Account::<T, I>::get(id, who) {
        if account.status.is_blocked() {
            return DepositConsequence::Blocked
        }
        if account.balance.checked_add(&amount).is_none() {
            return DepositConsequence::Overflow
        }
    } else {
        if amount < details.min_balance {
            return DepositConsequence::BelowMinimum
        }
        if !details.is_sufficient && !frame_system::Pallet::<T>::can_accrue_consumers(who,{
            return DepositConsequence::CannotCreate
        }
        if details.is_sufficient && details.sufficients.checked_add(1).is_none() {
            return DepositConsequence::Overflow
        }
    }
    
    DepositConsequence::Success
}
```

> substrate > frame > system > src > lib.rs > impl Palet > can_accrue_consumers()

```rust
pub fn can_accrue_consumers(who: &T::AccountId, amount: u32) -> bool {
    let a = Account::<T>::get(who);
    match a.consumers.checked_add(amount) {
        Some(c) => a.providers > 0 && c <= T::MaxConsumers::max_consumers(),
        None => false,
    }
}
```

After the checks, `increase_balance` is called, which when that account-asset_id storage item does not exist, it increments the consumers by one:

> substrate > frame > assets > src > functions.rs > impl Pallet > increase_balance()

```rust
    pub(super) fn increase_balance(
        id: T::AssetId,
        beneficiary: &T::AccountId,
        amount: T::Balance,
        check: impl FnOnce(
            &mut AssetDetails<T::Balance, T::AccountId, DepositBalanceOf<T, I>>,
        ) -> DispatchResult,
    ) -> DispatchResult {
        if amount.is_zero() {
            return Ok(())
        }

        Self::can_increase(id.clone(), beneficiary, amount, true).into_result()?;
        Asset::<T, I>::try_mutate(&id, |maybe_details| -> DispatchResult {
            let details = maybe_details.as_mut().ok_or(Error::<T, I>::Unknown)?;
            ensure!(details.status == AssetStatus::Live, Error::<T, I>::AssetNotLive);
            check(details)?;

            Account::<T, I>::try_mutate(&id, beneficiary, |maybe_account| -> DispatchResult {
                match maybe_account {
                    Some(ref mut account) => {
                        account.balance.saturating_accrue(amount);
                    },
                    maybe_account @ None => {
                        // Note this should never fail as it's already checked by
                        // `can_increase`.
                        ensure!(amount >= details.min_balance, TokenError::BelowMinimum);
                        *maybe_account = Some(AssetAccountOf::<T, I> {
                            balance: amount,
                            reason: Self::new_account(beneficiary, details, None)?,
                            status: AccountStatus::Liquid,
                            extra: T::Extra::default(),
                        });
                    },
                }
                Ok(())
            })?;
            Ok(())
        })?;
        Ok(())
    }
```

> substrate > frame > assets > src > functions.rs > impl Pallet > new_account()

```rust
    pub(super) fn new_account(
        who: &T::AccountId,
        d: &mut AssetDetails<T::Balance, T::AccountId, DepositBalanceOf<T, I>>,
        maybe_deposit: Option<(&T::AccountId, DepositBalanceOf<T, I>)>,
    ) -> Result<ExistenceReasonOf<T, I>, DispatchError> {
        let accounts = d.accounts.checked_add(1).ok_or(ArithmeticError::Overflow)?;
        let reason = if let Some((depositor, deposit)) = maybe_deposit {
            if depositor == who {
                ExistenceReason::DepositHeld(deposit)
            } else {
                ExistenceReason::DepositFrom(depositor.clone(), deposit)
            }
        } else if d.is_sufficient {
            frame_system::Pallet::<T>::inc_sufficients(who);
            d.sufficients += 1;
            ExistenceReason::Sufficient
        } else {
            frame_system::Pallet::<T>::inc_consumers(who)
                .map_err(|_| Error::<T, I>::UnavailableConsumer)?;
            // We ensure that we can still increment consumers once more because we could otherwise
            // allow accidental usage of all consumer references which could cause grief.
            if !frame_system::Pallet::<T>::can_inc_consumer(who) {
                frame_system::Pallet::<T>::dec_consumers(who);
                return Err(Error::<T, I>::UnavailableConsumer.into())
            }
            ExistenceReason::Consumer
        };
        d.accounts = accounts;
        Ok(reason)
    }
```

As you can see, `new_account` calls `inc_consumers` when the asset is new for that account.

Since the AssetHub parachain also has `MaxConsumers` set to 16, does that mean no one can hold more than 16 distinct assets in there?

For reference, here is the code I ran to test this:

```rust
mod sandbox {
    use super::*;
    use frame_support::traits::fungibles::Mutate as MutateFungibles;
    use frame_support::traits::fungible::Mutate as MutateFungible;
    use frame_support::traits::tokens::Preservation;

    #[test]
    fn transferring_more_than_max_consumers_tokens_to_one_user_fails() {
        new_test_ext().execute_with(|| {
            let receiver = 420u64;
            mock::Balances::mint_into(&receiver, PLMC * 1000);

            for admin in 0..20u64 {
                mock::Balances::mint_into(&admin, PLMC * 1000);
                mock::StatemintAssets::create(mock::RuntimeOrigin::signed(admin), (admin as u32).into(), admin, 1u128).unwrap();
                mock::StatemintAssets::mint_into((admin as u32).into(), &admin, 100_0_000_000_000).unwrap();

                <mock::StatemintAssets as MutateFungibles<AccountId>>::transfer((admin as u32).into(), &admin, &receiver, 50_0_000_000_000, Preservation::Preserve).unwrap();
            }
        });
    }

    #[test]
    fn minting_more_than_max_consumers_tokens_to_one_user_fails() {
        new_test_ext().execute_with(|| {
            let receiver = 420u64;
            mock::Balances::mint_into(&receiver, 10_000_000_000_u128 * 1000);

            for admin in 0..20u64 {
                mock::Balances::mint_into(&admin, 10_000_000_000_u128 * 1000);
                mock::StatemintAssets::create(mock::RuntimeOrigin::signed(admin), (admin as u32).into(), admin, 1u128).unwrap();
                mock::StatemintAssets::mint_into((admin as u32).into(), &receiver, 100_0_000_000_000).unwrap();

            }
        });
    }

}
```

---

Comment: I love the detailed question. I looks like you have already answered it yourself, I guess the question here is 'how you can make the accounts on your chain be able to hold more than 16 assets?'
Would creating these assets in a local pallet-assets solve the issue?

Comment: Thanks! it seems that this is the case yes.
What do you mean by a "local" pallet-assets? If you mean a new instance then I don't think so since the consumer count is stored in the frame-system pallet.
If I understood correctly, pallet-assets max out the consumer limit for that account would have implications on the functioning of other pallets :(

Answer (score 1):

An account can own more than 16 assets. If someone places a deposit (in DOT), `inc_consumers` won't be called.

```rust
        let reason = if let Some((depositor, deposit)) = maybe_deposit {
            if depositor == who {
                ExistenceReason::DepositHeld(deposit)
            } else {
                ExistenceReason::DepositFrom(depositor.clone(), deposit)
            }
        } else if d.is_sufficient {
            frame_system::Pallet::<T>::inc_sufficients(who);
            d.sufficients += 1;
            ExistenceReason::Sufficient
        } else {
            frame_system::Pallet::<T>::inc_consumers(who)
                // ...        
        }
```